# Why we should use 'compared to' rather than 'compare to' even though it is a present tense

Tags: grammaticality

For examples:

There are more car today, compared to yesterday

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7287/as-compared-to-vs-as-compare-to

Comment: A jolly good Question and I hope it looks easier in hindsight…

"compared" is the comment your sentence needs.

"compare" would be an instruction or request that a comparison be made.

"compare (to)" would be an instruction or request that something be "compared to" something else…

Answer (score 0):

> There are more **cars** today compared to yesterday.

This can be understood as "more **cars** exist today compared to yesterday."

**Compared** is a passive past participle. It introduces a reduced clause that acts as an adverbial free modifier.

"compared to yesterday" is a passive form and is a shortened form of "**when/if the number of cars is** compared to **that of** yesterday.

> There are more cars today **compare** to yesterday.
>   This makes no sense. "compare" must be the present tense (or bare infinitive) of the verb. Neither of these forms of the verb can introduce a clause that acts as a free modifier.